# php Code Prints out in screen instead of executing?

Tags: php

It worked exactly fine few hours back, but now its showing the code in the browser instead of executing it. Rechecked the code thrice, checked with the file extension, even retyped the whole code into a new php, this bug is haunting me..

My code goes like this:

```
<?php include('usersign.php'); ?>

<?php

$servername  = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "******";
$dbname = "userdatabase";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$category1 = $_POST['category1'];
$category2 = $_POST['category2'];
$category3 = $_POST['category3'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$date = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date('M-d,Y H:i:s');


$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, email, category1, category2, category3, password, date)
VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$category1', '$category2', '$category3', '$password', '$date')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("You have succesfully registerd with userdatabase Please login..")';
echo '</script>';
echo '<a href="usersign.php"></a>';
}
else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Any suggestions are Appreciated...

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not even escaping the user input... Never ever ever never use user input without properly escaping it first...

Comment: it worked... i just restarted the server. thanks man.. why dont you post it as  an answer...@MagnusEriksson

Comment: Added it as an answer.... and as a rule of thumb, if something just worked and you haven't change anything, always start by restarting it. Things crash silently sometimes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to restart your web server, since you say that it just worked...
If it still doesn't work, check for errors in your web server logs and you will most likely get some more information what's actually going on.

Comment: How do I do that if my webserver is from a hosting company?

Comment: @ChristofferHjärtström - Then you should contact the hosting company's support.